# "Cannot decode string with wide characters" appears on a weird place

Tags: perl, unicode

I am trying to use XML::RAI perl module on UTF8 coded text and I still have error I don't really understand... here is the code (it shouldn't do anything useful yet):

```
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use XML::RAI;
use Encode;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;


sub readFromWeb{
    my $address = shift;
    my $request = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $address );
    my $response = $ua->request( $request );
    return unless $response->code == 200;

    return decode("utf8", $response->content());
}

sub readFromRSS{
    my $address=shift;
    my $content = readFromWeb $address;
    my $rai = XML::RAI->parse_string($content);
          #this line "causes" the error
}


readFromRSS("http://aktualne.centrum.cz/export/rss-hp.phtml");
     #I am testing it on this particular RSS
```

the error is:

```
 Cannot decode string with wide characters at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i686-linux/Encode.pm line 166.
```

I don't have a clue if that's my fault or the fault of XML::RAI. I don't see where these wide characters can be, if $content is already decoded from utf8...

edit: for some reason I still don't understand, removing the "decode" part actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is double-decoding. `XML::RAI::parse_string()` apparently
expects an UTF-8 encoded document and does the decoding itself. If you
pass in a string that is already decoded, decoding it a second time will fail,
of course:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw( decode );
use LWP::Simple qw( get );

my $xml = get("http://aktualne.centrum.cz/export/rss-hp.phtml");

$xml = decode('UTF-8', $xml);
$xml = decode('UTF-8', $xml); # dies: Cannot decode string with wide characters ...
```

So just skip the `decode()` step and you'll be fine.