# How To Detect Decoded String

Tags: perl, utf8-decode

I'm chasing a bug in Perl code that seems to fundamentally be a version of this:

["Cannot decode string with wide characters" appears on a weird place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112828/cannot-decode-string-with-wide-characters-appears-on-a-weird-place)

Basically, under certain conditions, `Encode::decode('utf8', $string)` is getting called twice on the same string, and hilarity ensues.  Now, the best solution is to figure out what conditions are causing the double-decode and stop that from happening.  Unfortunately, this is mature production code for feature-rich product; figuring out those conditions and fixing them in a way that doesn't introduce regression errors looks to be challenging.

Is there some fast reliable way to detect whether a string has already been decoded from utf8?  Inserting "if" statements before those calls feels a tad kludgy, but ought to be a pretty safe fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode has an [is_utf8](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#Messing-with-Perl%27s-Internals) function:

> **is_utf8(STRING [, CHECK])**
>
> [INTERNAL] Tests whether the UTF8 flag is turned on in the STRING.
>   If CHECK is true, also checks the data in STRING for being well-formed
>   UTF-8. Returns true if successful, false otherwise.

Notice that the caption of the documentation is  *"Messing with Perl's Internals"*, this function might change in future perl versions.

Comment: @BlairHippo, Note that this does the same as `utf8::is_utf8`, except that the latter is builtin, meaning you don't need to load any modules to use it. Keep in mind that neither accurately returns whether the string has been decoded or not.

Answer (score 5):

It's impossible to correctly detect whether a scalar contains a decoded string or not. There's no way to communicate that info to Perl, so there's no way for it to communicate it to you. At best, one can guess. There are some heuristics you could use. From most reliable to least:

1. If the string contains characters above 255, it's not encoded. This is exactly what causes the "wide character" warning/error.

   ```
   utf8::encode($s) if /[^\x00-\xFF]/;
   ```
2. If the scalar would be encoded using UTF-8 if it was encoded and the scalar contains valid UTF-8, it's probably encoded.
3. If the scalar would be encoded using UTF-8 if it was encoded and the scalar does not contain valid UTF-8, it's probably decoded.

   ```
   utf8::encode($s) if !utf8::decode(my $tmp = $s);
   ```
4. If the scalar's `UTF8` flag is on, then the string is probably decoded.
5. If the scalar's `UTF8` flag is off, then the string is probably not decoded.

   ```
   utf8::encode($s) if utf8::is_utf8($s);
   ```

You should decode all your inputs and encode all your outputs.

Comment: One could also search for NUL bytes or newlines encoded using UTF-16, UCS-2 and UTF-32/UCS-4, but that's getting pretty specific.